# Outlook email template style are broken

Tags: html, outlook

as part of my job i need to create email-templates to send it to customer. challenging part is all mail's(gmail,yahoo,mobile apps) working fine with richness, as it will support the html format. however It should support outlook also with same kind of rich in looks. I am using table format for the same.

if i use as a single image, outlook will ask to download it. we want to show the customers about the offers without downloading it. if I am coding with css styles then in outlook it is looking very bad.

Please suggest me any plug-in or alternative solution for Outlook desktop.

This is sample code that i have used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>sample.com</title>
<style> @media screen {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}
img{display:block;}
a{text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-size:16px;}
span{color:#D24369;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"style="background:#0f0708"align="center">
         <tbody>
         <!--corporate section-->
          <tr>
            <td height="10%" width="50%" align="right" style="padding-right:20px;padding-top:10px">
                <span style="color:#fff;font-size:8px;font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;">sample text</span>
            </td>
            <td width="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" rowspan="1"style="padding-right:2px;padding-top:10px" >
                <img src="images/sample.jpg" width="150" height="87" style="display:block;"/>
            </td>
            <td width="50"></td>
          </tr>
          <!-- corporate logo end-->
            <tr>
              <td align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" border="0" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="images/header-1-1-image.jpg" width="750" height="906" style="display:block"/></a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                 <td>
                    <table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                                <td width="4%"></td>
                                <td width="22%" align="center" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ; color:#fff; font-size:10px;">Available on: <strong style="font-size:12px;"><a href="http://www.zigy.com/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fff;">Zigy.com</a></strong></td>
                                <td width="1%" align=""><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/app-icon_1_1.jpg"}}" width="33" height="34" alt=""/></a></td>
                                <td width="1%"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/app-icon_2_1.jpg"}}" width="31" height="34" alt=""/></a></td>
                                <td width="9%"></td>
                                <td style="color:#fff;font-size:8px;">*This offer is not applicable on Health Bonanza and similar special offers</td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-top:1px solid #fff;line-height:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="90%" align="center" style="color:#fff;font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size:10px">To order products, you can also email us at <a href="mailto:rx@sample.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-size:14px;">rx@sample.com</a></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #fff;line-height:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Pavani

Answer (score 0):

I have found some success using zurb email templates as a starting point.  One benefit is they are responsive as well.

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates

Comment: I have tried the template mentioned above, I didn't work for me :(

Comment: I have had some success with this as well.  https://builder.stamplia.com/  Honestly no template or resource will be perfect out of the box.  I have always had to modify it a bit to work with what I needed.  I would also suggest avoiding css, and try to do it inline.  Basicly everything you would never do on a website :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't accepted images from the sender before, or added them to the address book, then Outlook will always ask to download images for security purposes.

I recommend not making email templates that consist entirely of images but rather a good combination of text and images/colour, just in case some decide not to download images.

Make sure to add alt txt to images!